# About an infinite product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a curiosity as regards the infinite product below. I wonder why Mathematica v.8.0. says
the limit is $1$. This is not true.

```
Limit[(Product[(1 - a/n^2), {n, 1, Infinity}])^(1/Sqrt[a]),  a -> Infinity]
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not true?

Comment: @Pinguin Dirk Consider $\sqrt{a}$ is an integer.

Comment: @TeakeNutma see the message above.

Comment: Simpler example: `In[4]:= Limit[(Sin[x]/x)^(1/x), x -> Infinity]

Out[4]= 1` I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature. Will investigate when time permits.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Daniel, do note that when operating with real/rational numbers we end up with a `1` and when we add the assumptions about the integers we get the `0`. That's regarding the OP's question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau did you consider $\sqrt{a}$ an integer? Check that and see what happens.

Comment: (1) I was kinda' dimly aware of the issue at hand. That was sort of the point of the more direct example. More concise still would be to remove the x^(1/x) denominator, as the numerator shows the same pahology. (2) It's due to some interval handling that is, provisionally, changed. If nothing breaks as a consequence then this will behave better in a future release.

Comment: V10.1 now gives the result `Interval[{0, 1}]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for information. Glad for this improvement. :-)

Comment: @MichaelE2 V12.x give `1` again. (Arguably better/worse result than `Interval[{0,1}]`?)

Comment: @Silvia Probably worse in that mathematically the limit  `Limit[p, a -> Infinity]`, where `p = (Sin[Sqrt[a] Pi]/(Sqrt[a] Pi))^(1/Sqrt[a])` is the product, does not exist unless one restricts the domain to `Sin[Sqrt[a] Pi] != 0`. OTOH, it might be considered better in that one could argue that the product "diverges" to zero when $\sqrt{a}$ is an integer, and that the domain of `a` should be so restricted. However, the limit is computed as `1` without such a restriction, and that is incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for sharing the opinion. I fully agree with you. It would be nice if we have something like `ConditionalExpression[1, n ∉ Integers]` as the result.

Answer (score 10):

Any ideas why it is not true ? Typo/s ?

Running Win 8, *Mathematica* 9.0.1 the result is the same and also on my Ubuntu desktop with *Mathematica* 9.0.0 and WolframAlpha: [Check here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%5C%5BPi%5D%5E%28-%281/Sqrt%5Ba%5D%29%29%20%28Sin%5BSqrt%5Ba%5D%20%5C%5BPi%5D%5D/Sqrt%5Ba%5D%29%5E%281/Sqrt%5Ba%5D%29,%20%20a%20-%3E%20Inf%5D)

Computing the `(Product[(1 - a/n^2), {n, 1, ∞}])^(1/Sqrt[a])` yields the result:

$$ \pi ^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}} \left(\frac{\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}} $$

Taking the limit of it as $a \to \infty$ is equal to $1$

And plotting it:

[image: Plot]

Edit: Assuming $\sqrt{a}\in \mathbb{Z}$ and taking the limit of the product we end up with $0$:

```
Limit[(Product[(1 - a/n^2), {n, 1, ∞}])^(1/Sqrt[a]), 
      a -> ∞, Assumptions :> Sqrt[a] ∈ Integers]
```

Comment: What if $\sqrt{a}$ is an integer?

Comment: @Chris'ssister How about now ?

Comment: Thanks so much! Why do you think Mathematica says the limit exists when it doesn't?

Comment: Technically speaking the limit still exists before we made the assumptions, but the "problem" is *Mathematica* was operating with Real numbers.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 10):

$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left|\,1-\frac{a}{n^2}\,\right|^{1/\sqrt{a}}
$$
As $a\to\infty$, each term is like $1+\frac{\log(a)}{n^2\sqrt{a}}$ and as $\frac{\log(a)}{n^2\sqrt{a}}$ is absolutely summable to something around $\frac{\log(a)}{\sqrt{a}}\frac{\pi^2}{6}\to0$ I would say that the product limits to $1$, unless $a=n^2$ for some $n$. So the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: did you consider the case when $\sqrt{a}$ is an integer?

Comment: If you take any $\sqrt{a}$ integer then the limit is precisely $0$. $$\pi ^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}} \left(\frac{\sin \left(\pi  \sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}}$$

Comment: @Chris'ssister: and the expression you give there goes to $1$ as $a\to\infty$

Comment: Definitely no. It's precisely 0 when $\sqrt{a}$ is integer.

Comment: Oh, yes. one term is 0. So the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It's nice to see you over here robjohn

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks! This question points out what seems to be a bug in Mathematica's handling of the limit of infinite products. It doesn't seem to check that a term can be zero no matter how big the limiting variable is. Is there a place to report such things? Does Wolfram check this site for bug reports? Of course, I can't edit tags here (how frustrating :-)

Comment: I think the infinite product is ok.  The problem can be boiled down to `Limit[Sin[x]^(1/x), x -> Infinity]` or `Limit[Sin[1/x]^x, x -> 0]` -- both give `1`.  Just a guess: Sometimes *Mathematica*'s methods are generic, that is, they can miss a discrete (or measure-zero) set of exceptions.